# SASS --watch command won't work

Tags: css, npm, command-line, sass, frontend

I have a quick question regarding sass. When I first learned the basics of sass I was introduced to the "--watch" flag that would compile my sass to css live while coding only now when I went back to using sass the command line doesn't show it as a valid command. Why is that? Is it a bug or was it removed and if so what's the best way to compile sass now?? I'm using Dart Sass.

Comment: Which sass are you using? Node-sass, the ruby gem? It’s important for writing the proper answer. Also the OS information will help.

Comment: when i check the version it says compiled with dart not gem or or node.

Comment: You have several ways to install dart sass. Does your project includes a node_modules folder or a package.json file? When you learned the basics of sass, you did that on a specific project/folder? If you can’t run `sass` as a command probably is not installed on your system or the binary is not defined in your path.